# Working with component state or props inside Redux mapDispatchToProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm a Redux/React beginner still trying to wrap my held around the component of `dispatch` within the Redux ecosystem. So far, the way I've issued Redux actions within my components is by directly calling the `dispatch()` function of my component props:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {searchType: state.searchType}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SearchForm);
```

And then, I have a handler function tied to an `onClick` event:

```
  handleOptionChange(changeEvent) {

    this.setState({selectedOption: changeEvent.target.value});
    this.props.dispatch(setSearchType(this.state.selectedOption));
  }
```

However, I've been trying to implement `mapDispatchToProps` instead. This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43996066/react-redux-mapdispatchtoprops-vs-this-props-dispatch) describes some of the benefits to using `mapDispatchToProps` instead of simply `this.props.dispatch`. However, I've struggling to find a way to integrate my component props or state into `mapDispatchToProps`. I want to write something like this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    setSearchType : dispatch(setSearchType(this.props.option))
  }
}
```

`this.props.option` is a prop passed down to identify the configuration being selected for a particular button (in this a Radio Button). And then simply call:

```
  handleOptionChange(changeEvent) {

    this.setState({selectedOption: changeEvent.target.value});
    this.props.setSearchType(); // <--- this line is new
  }
```

However, clearly, `this` in `mapDispatchToProps` is undefined, since the function is defined outside the scope of my component. In the SO post I referenced, and in the tutorial materials and documentation, `mapDispatchToProps` is always sending an action that does not rely on a component state/props. What's the best practice for introducing a component's state/props into `mapDispatchToProps`?

Comment: Frankly I don't see real problem here. You are free to pass any data into a `mapDispatchToProps`'s function, incl. `this` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply define your dispatcher as a function that accepts the props as parameter:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    setSearchType : option => dispatch(setSearchType(option))
  }
}
```

Then pass the parameter when calling it:

```
this.props.setSearchType(this.props.option)
```

Mind performance issues though when binding onClick to a function on every render.  See [this](https://daveceddia.com/avoid-bind-when-passing-props/) article for more info.

Comment: Wow. This was such a simple answer. I'm kind of embarrassed I didn't think this through.

Comment: I recommend using the "object shorthand" for `mapDispatch`:  `connect(null, {setSearchType})(MyComponent)`.