# this.props.dispatch is not a function in react with redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am calling api with redux action, so i created the reducers, action and store. But when i calling the redux action from the view part. I am getting the following error.

> this.props.dispatch is not a function

Below is my reducer, actions and view part(React) Code which can help you to understand the code.

**Note: when i console.log(this.props), I am not getting dispatch() function.**

**actions.js**

```
import { 
 FETCH_WORKS_SUCCESS,
 FETCH_WORKS_FAILURE
} from './actionTypes'

export function fetchFeaturedWork(){
  return dispatch => {
   return fetch("https://api.com/api/wp-json/customapi/all_posts?category=work&featured=true")
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(json => {
     dispatch(fetchFeaturedWorkSuccess(json.works));
     return json.works;
   })
  };
}

export const fetchFeaturedWorkSuccess = works => ({
   type: FETCH_WORKS_SUCCESS,
   payload: { works }
});
```

**reducer.js**

```
import {
 OPEN_MENU,
 CLOSE_MENU,
 SET_DEVICE_TYPE,
 FETCH_WORKS_SUCCESS,
 FETCH_WORKS_FAILURE
} from '../actions/actionTypes'

const initialState = {
 isMenuOpen: null,
 isMobile: false,
 error:null,
 works:[] 
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
 switch (action.type) {
  case OPEN_MENU:
   return {...state, isMenuOpen: true}
  case CLOSE_MENU:
   return {...state, isMenuOpen: false}
  case SET_DEVICE_TYPE: 
   return {...state, isMobile: action.isMobile} 
  case FETCH_WORKS_SUCCESS:
   return {...state,works:action.payload.works}
  case FETCH_WORKS_FAILURE:
   return {...state,error:action.payload.error,works:[]}
  default:
   return state
 }
}

export default reducer;
```

**store.js**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './reducers/reducer';
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

let store = createStore(rootReducer,applyMiddleware(thunk))
export default store
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Slider from "react-slick";
import Footer from '../footer'
import './index.css';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { openMenu,fetchFeaturedWork } from '../../actions/actionCreators'
import Header from '../header'
import arrowRight from '../../images/arrow-right.svg'
import arrowLeft from '../../images/arrow-left.svg'

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isMobile: state && state.isMobile
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
 openMenu: (isMobile) => dispatch(openMenu(ownProps.isMobile))
})

class Work extends Component {
  getImgSlider = (slider) => {
   this.imgSlider = slider
  }
  getTextSlider = (slider) => {
   this.textSlider = slider
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.dispatch(fetchFeaturedWork());
  }

  render() {
   let className = 'idz_work'
   if (this.props.isMobile) {
     className = 'idle'
   }
   return (
    <div>
     {
      this.props.isMobile ?
        null
        :
        <Link to='/home'>
          <div className='idz_sidebar' style={{ left: 0 }}>
            <div>
              <label>FEATURED</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Link>
    }
    <div className={className}>
      {!this.props.isMobile &&
        <Header logo="dark"/>
      }
      <div className="content">
        <label className="light-gray" style={this.props.isMobile ? { fontSize: '1.3rem' } : { fontSize: '2rem' }}>Featured Works</label>
        <hr style={this.props.isMobile ? { marginBottom: '0.5rem', marginTop: '0.5rem' } : {}} />
        <hr style={this.props.isMobile ? { marginBottom: '0.5rem', marginTop: '0.5rem' } : {}} />
        <label className="light-gray" style={this.props.isMobile ? { fontSize: '1.3rem' } : { fontSize: '2rem' }}>All Works</label>
        <hr style={this.props.isMobile ? { marginBottom: '0.5rem', marginTop: '0.5rem' } : {}} />
        <hr />
      </div>
      {this.props.isMobile ? null : <Footer />}
    </div>
  </div>
);
}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Work);
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [React Redux mapDispatchToProps vs this.props.dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43996066/react-redux-mapdispatchtoprops-vs-this-props-dispatch/43996333#43996333) or [How does connect work without mapDispatchToProps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670146/how-does-connect-work-without-mapdispatchtoprops/41671030#41671030)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Redux mapDispatchToProps vs this.props.dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43996066/react-redux-mapdispatchtoprops-vs-this-props-dispatch)

Answer (score 1):

When you use mapDispatchToProps, dispatch is not longer available in props. So, either get rid of mapDispatchToProps and use this.props.dispatch. Or move all dispatch functions to mapDispatchToProps.

Comment: actually i don't know functionality of mapDispatchToProps. Can you please explain me what it is? and you can see, I used the this.props.dispatch and getting the error "this.props.dispatch is not a function"

Comment: It defines a prop (of function type) to dispatch an action to the store. From your code, `openMenu: (isMobile) => dispatch(openMenu(ownProps.isMobile))`, openMenu is the function prop that you have defined. It dispatches an action  - `openMenu()` to the store. The result of `openMenu()` is an action.

Comment: move `this.props.dispatch(fetchFeaturedWork());` to mapDispatchToProps just like the other function you have there.

Comment: I have done but getting the error. can you please edit the code?

Comment: I saw in my code. I am not getting dispatch() function when i console.log(this.props);